# Where is the BASEDIR for MySQL installed with APT on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, mysql

According to the MySQL document, [2.10.1 Initializing the Data Directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html):

> 1. Change location into the top-level directory of your MySQL installation, represented here by `BASEDIR`:
>
>    `shell> cd BASEDIR`
>
>    `BASEDIR` is likely to be something like `/usr/local/mysql` or `/usr/local`. The following steps assume that you have changed location to this directory.
>
>    You will find several files and subdirectories in the `BASEDIR` directory. The most important for installation purposes is the `bin` subdirectory, which contains the server as well as client and utility programs.

I've checked `/usr/local/mysql and /usr/local`, but neither of them contains anything related to MySQL. `which mysql` returns `/usr/bin/mysql`, but I don't think `/usr/bin` would be MySQL's base directory.

The document says I need to create a directory called `mysql-files` under `BASEDIR`, so I want to know where to find it.

Comment: You don't need to create anything in the data directory. The `mysql-server` package (or `mariadb-server` installs a ready to use MySQL server. You just need to create *databases*

Answer (score 1):

`/var/lib/mysql`

But to be sure you can do a

`locate ibdata1`

and when found it will also show the directory mysql is in.

Comment: BTW, the debian or ubuntu packages for mysql are already creating these directories, and you don't need to explicitly create them